# RSpec 3 best practices and expect_any_instance_of in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm looking for best-practice alternatives to `expect_any_instance_of`, because the RSpec documentation discourages using `expect_any_instance_of`:

> This feature is sometimes useful when working with legacy code, though in general we
> discourage its use for a number of reasons: ...  [[reference]](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance)

I use `expect_any_instance_of` a lot in cases where I want to test that a method will be called when certain conditions are met, but where the object will be loaded in a different scope.

For example, when writing a controller spec, I simply want to test that the correct method is called with the correct parameters on an instance of X.

Answer (score 12):

Ok, well. The answer is - it depends :)

Here are some things, that may help you:

**1) Have a look at the way you are testing code. There are (in general) two ways to do it.**

Suppose you have this class:

```
class UserUpdater
  def update(user)
    user.update_attributes(updated: true)
  end
end
```

Then you can test it in two ways:

Stub everything:

```
it 'test it' do
  user = double(:user, update_attributes: true)
  expect(user).to receive(:update_attributes).with(updated: true)
  UserUpdater.new.update(user)
end
```

Minimal (or no) stubbing:

```
let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let(:update) { UserUpdater.new.update(user) }

it { expect { update }.to change { user.reload.updated }.to(true) }
```

I prefer the second way - because it is more natural and gives me much more confidence in my tests.

Back to your example - are you sure that you want to check the method call when the controller action runs? In my opinion - it is better to check the result. Everything behind it should be tested separately - for example, if your controller has a service called - you will test everything about this service in it's own spec, and how the action works in general (some kind of integration tests) in the controller spec.

**2. Check what is returned, not how it works:**

For example, you have a service, which can find or build a user for you:

```
class CoolUserFinder
   def initialize(email)
      @email = email
   end

   def find_or_initialize
      find || initialize
   end

   private

   def find
     User.find_by(email: email, role: 'cool_guy')
   end

   def initialize
     user = User.new(email: email)
     user.maybe_cool_guy!

     user
   end
end
```

And you can test it without stubbing on any instance:

```
let(:service) { described_class.new(email) }
let(:email) { 'foo@bar.org' }
let(:user) { service.find_or_initialize }

context 'when user does not exist' do
  it { expect(user).to be_a User }
  it { expect(user).to be_new_record }
  it { expect(user.email).to eq 'foo@bar.org' }
  it { expect(user.role).to eq 'maybe_cool_guy' }
  it { expect(user).to be_on_hold }
end

context 'when user already exists' do
  let!(:old_user) { create :user, email: email }

  it { expect(user).to be_a User }
  it { expect(user).not_to be_new_record }
  it { expect(user).to eq old_user }
  it { expect(user.role).to eq 'cool_guy' }
  it { expect(user).not_to be_on_hold }
end
```

**3. And finally sometimes you REALLY need to stub any instance. And it's ok  - sometimes shit happens :)**

Sometimes you can also replace any_instance with stub like this:

```
allow(File).to receive(:open).and_return(my_file_double)
```

I hope it will help you a bit and I hope it is not too long :)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response @unkmas. I avidly avoid adding what are really model specs to my controller specs. I prefer to thoroughly test the model in model specs and then keep my controller specs focused on: did the right method get called and did I receive the correct response (i.e. the only things controllers are generally supposed to do). The beauty of the any_instance stuff is that I don't have to care how it gets instantiated or know much about it; I just care that it gets called. To me, it's far more elegant, so I don't really understand what the RSpec team has against it.

Comment: That's wy I added second item in the list :) The problem in `stub_any_instance` is that you don't really know which object have been called. For example - somewhere inside your business-logic you take two user objects from the db. And your specs will not tell you, which of them received method call.

Comment: That's easily controlled for (called when id matches, not called when not). Often, what's returned from a controller says nothing about what happened (e.g. some action initiated and only status code 20x returned) or is complicated to stub, resulting in controller tests highly coupled to implementation. The RSpec team says they don't use any_instance stubs, but I know they want to encourage decoupled, simple tests, so I wonder what they do in these cases. If there isn't any better best practice, then I'll continue what I'm doing because it results in clean tests.