# How do I convert an `expect_any_instance_of()` (as it is deprecated) so my carrierwave rspec tests still pass?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, carrierwave, rspec-rails

From the rspec documentation, `expect_any_instance_of()` has been deprecated. What I haven't found so far, though, is an easy way to replace that method with another. Everything I've tried so far fails and especially, the method that is expected to be mocked gets called.

```
context 'test Foo' do
  before(:each) do
    info = double(
      size: 12345,
      close: true
    )
    allow(Blah).to receive(:open).and_return(info)  # this one works
  end                                                                       

  it 'returns false on failure' do
    # This expect_any_instance_of() works like a charm
    expect_any_instance_of(MyUploader).to receive(:process_with_some_tool).and_return(false)

    uploader = MyUploader.new(create(:my_object, data: nil))

    # These expect()'s fails
    expect(MyUploader).to receive(:process_with_some_tool).and_return(true)
    expect(uploader).to receive(:process_with_some_tool).and_return(true)

    uploader.store!(trigger_data)
  end
end
```

The first `expect(MyUploader)` (so with the class name), I also tried to place inside the `before` block. I kind of was expecting it to fail anyway since the class name of the `uploader` object looks like this on a run (and of course the number changes on each run):

```
MyUploader::Uploader47181996911040
```

However, I don't understand why the `expect(uploader)` (so with the object I just allocated) fails too. Since I'm attached to the very object I created, why wouldn't it have that `:process_with_some_tool` event mocked and just return `true`?

I have a `puts "CALLED\n"` in my `:process_with_some_tool` and I see that message when I use the `expect()`. I do not see it when I use the `expect_any_instance_of()`. So the former doesn't mock anything and the latter mocks as expected...

I also tried to wrap my head around the [Method stubs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-4/docs/method-stubs) help page, but again, I've not been able to make it work.

So my question is: how do we transform an `expect_any_instance_of()` so it actually works?

*Note: I'm new to Ruby, Rails, RSpec and all of that. I suspect it's an easy one but I just don't see how to make it all work...*

---

The implementation is proprietary, but here is a basic representation of what I use:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include Inspectable

  version :cleanup do
    process :func1
    process :func2
    process :func3
    after :store, :check_size
  end

  def func1
    # Do work
  end

  def func2
    if info.close
      tmpfile = 'temp_file1.ext'
      successful_processing = process_with_some_tool1(tmpfile)
      log "message 1" unless successful_processing
    end

    if !info.close
      tmpfile = 'temp_file2.ext'
      successful_processing = process_with_some_tool2(tmpfile)
      log "message 2" unless successful_processing
    end
  end

  def func3
    # Do work
  end

  def process_with_some_tool1(tmpfile)
    puts "TOOL1 RUN"
    system %Q{mytool1 -a -b -c "#{tmpfile}"}
  end

  def process_with_some_tool2(tmpfile)
    puts "TOOL2 RUN"
    system %Q{mytool2 -a -b -c "#{tmpfile}"}
  end

  def check_size
    begin
      if size < 100
        raise "Too small"
      end
    rescue => error
      log "some message"
    end
  end
end
```

This is a basic representation of what I have. The code is proprietary so I can't just copy paste the whole thing.

What I see is the `"TOOL2 RUN"` message when I expect that one (and tool1) to be a stub because of the `expect()`.

Note that I don't see `store` being implemented here. So it comes from the base class.

---

Update:

I see that the `store!()` calls `cache()` and that calls `versions!()` and the `versions!()` implementation includes the following initialization function:

```
    def build_version(name, options)                                        
      uploader = Class.new(self)                                            
      const_set("Uploader#{uploader.object_id}".gsub('-', '_'), uploader)   
      uploader.version_names += [name]                                      
      ...snip...
    end
```

As we can see, this function creates a new class and name it "Uploader<#id>" which is exactly what I see when I print the class/object_id to the console.

Checking all the IDs, I can now see that the actual object used in the test is one that this `Class.new()` created and not the one I create in my code.

This `build_version` method comes from `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/carrierwave-0.11.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb`. It is part of the uploader feature which caches files for your tests. It looks like it's not limited to caching files, though... Now I'm wondering whether I'd have access to that cached object and be allowed to attach my `expect()` or `allow()` to that version instead. I'll specifically check with the [Carrierwave implementers](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave). It's more likely that they'd have a solution to this problem.

Comment: Check this question , I believe its the same as what you are asking, however, I won't  make this question as a duplicate as the other question doesn't have an accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991302/rspec-3-best-practices-and-expect-any-instance-of-in-rails

Comment: @sameera207, yeah, I found that Q/A and tried what's in there (at least I think I replicated that code properly) and it still didn't work in my case...

Comment: @AlexisWilke is your RSpec configured with Aggregate Failures (https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-9/docs/aggregating-failures) ? Because if it's not - the `expect(MyUploader)` fails the the rest of the block is not even run.

Comment: Try removind `expect(MyUploader)` line and tell us what's the result.

Comment: @Grzegorz, the code sample above shows all the lines I checked. I checked them one at a time. So I already tested without the `exprct(MyUploader)`.

Comment: Ok, that was confusing. In such case - I'm as baffled as you are :) Can you share MyUploader implementaion? Especially `.initialize` and `#store!` method?

Comment: I added a representation of the code. I don't have an `initialize` or `store!`. I suspect the base class functions are used for those two.

Comment: @Grzegorz, okay, your comment about `.initialize` made me think that something in the initialization could be going _wrong_. The fact is that the uploader carrierwave creates a new instance of my object and the test is run against that copy. This is why my stubs are _ignored_.